# Is it a jointly concave function of $(x,y,z)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have following function $$f(x,y,z)=xy\log(1+\frac{z}{xy})$$ where $x,y,z$ are all $\geq 0$. Is it a jointly concave function of $(x,y,z)$? Thank you in advance.

Edit:

After fixing $z=1$ I am trying to check whether $xy\log(1+\frac{1}{xy})$ is jointly concave with respect to $(x,y)$ or not. The determinant of the Hessian matrix for $xy\log(1+\frac{1}{xy})$ is given as follows $$1-\left(-2-xy+(1+xy)^2\log(1+\frac{1}{xy})\right)^2$$ Now if the above determinant is greater than or equal to $0$ then $xy\log(1+\frac{1}{xy})$ is a concave function.

Comment: Please don't use a determinant test. It is not sufficient to establish convexity in most cases and can lead you astray.

Comment: @MichaelGrant actually for my edit part I know that the $(1,1)$ entry of the Hessian matrix is $< 0$ therefore I wanted to check that whether the determinant is $\geq 0$ or not. This is because I read somewhere that a function of two variables is jointly concave if the determinant of its Hessian is $\geq 0$ and its $(1,1)$ entry is $<0$.

Comment: Sure, that works for two variables. The problem is it works only for two. If you want to have a rule in your pocket works for more variables, you need to look elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO. Here is a proof by contradiction.

Assume that $f$ is concave. Then, the following function must be concave on $z>0$ as a composition with a linear transformation:
$$
g(z) = f(z, z, z) = z^2 \log(1+1/z).
$$
From concavity, we conclude that $g''(z) \leq 0$ for all $z>0$. However, 
$$g''(1)=2\log(2)-5/4 \approx 0.1363 > 0,$$
which is a contradiction.